# with GTX 1050 ti, tensorflow gpu memory usage 100%, but load ~0

Tags: tensorflow

I have an GTX 1050 ti (4GB) and i5 CPU, 8GB memory.
I successfully installed tensorflow-gpu with cuda driver on win10 and the test shows that tensorflow is actually using the gpu (snapshot):[image]

However, when carrying out the training with CNN, while the GPU memory is always 100%, the GPU load is qualsi 0 with some spikes # 30%~70%:

Is it normal ?

[image]

EDIT: While the GPU occupation is qualsi 0 with spikes, the CPU load is fixed at 100% during the training.

**EDIT2: I did read somewhere that the CPU could be high while GPU be low if there are a lot of operations of data copy between CPU and GPU. But I am using the official tensorflow object detection api for the training so I am totally unaware of the possible place in code.**

Comment: Tensorflow will block the memory on the GPU for the python process so the memory consumption won't vary. Regarding the utilisation: GPU usage is very model and batch size dependent. Have a look here to make sure you input pipeline and data formats are optimised. As a starting tip: try increasing the batch size.

Comment: @O.Gindele thank you. I tried the tensorflow object detection api, with different batch_size (froim 32 to 2). The result does not change much. The one info I did not methion is that the CPU occupation is fixed at 100% during the training.

Comment: Can you try increasing the batch size instead of lowering it?

Comment: @O.Gindele Yeah I tried 32, 16, 8, 4, and 2. Pretty much the same result. I updated my original post with EDIT2.

Comment: @captainst How did installed tensorflow-gpu for 1050ti. I tried but it gave me an error. I am using cuda 10.0 toolkit, cudnn 7.4. The error I am getting is due to pywrap_tensorflow not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is normal behavior in most cases.

TensorFlow books the entire GPU memory initially.

The load on the GPU is dependent upon the data it is getting for processing.

If the data loading operation is slow, then most of the time GPU is waiting for data to get copied from disk to the GPU, and during that time it is not performing any work. That is what you see in your screen.

Comment: Thank you. While the GPU occupation is qualsi 0 with spikes, the CPU load is fixed at 100% during the training, which makes me confusing.

Comment: CPU load at `100%` has nothing to do with the GPU load. It simply means that the CPU is being heavily used (perhaps for preprocessing ?). 
Now what may happen is that preprocessed data is transferred to the GPU for processing. If that transfer is not fast enough, then GPU will keep on waiting for data for a long time leading to intermittent 0% load. More can be said about this only if the code is posted.

Comment: Good point.  I did read somewhere that the CPU could be high while GPU be low if there are a lot of operations of data copy between CPU and GPU. But I am using the official tensorflow object detection api for the training so I am totally unaware of the possible place in code

Comment: People report a wide range of speed problems with the API. It is not so easy to debug.
You should also remember that GPU also plays a role here. AT what termperature you are using a card also plays a role here. If for example, the ambient temperature is high around, your GPU will soon reach its max operating temperature and slow itself down in the lack of adequate cooling thereby leading to 0% usage.

Comment: Thank you again. Finally I upgrade the tensorflow to ver1.10.0, and downloaded the lastest version of tensorflow model (which includes object detection). The training time / step decreases almost 10x!. Now the GPU occupation is around 20~25%.